# IPv6 FAQ and checklist for a home user?

Tags: ipv6

Can we start an IPv6 FAQ and checklist for a (*)Ubuntu home user, covering both hardware and software?

The answers can cover the following areas:

- ISP readiness.
- Home router readiness and configuration.
- (*)Ubuntu configuration.
- Since when has (*)Ubuntu been IPv6 ready? (Do we really need the latest version of (*)Ubuntu?)
- How to configure LAN and cross-LAN services (SSH, /etc/hosts, etc.)?
- and more.

Comment: Linux has been IPv6 ready for at least 10 years.
You prob. need to set up a tunnel if you want to route IPv6, as most western ISP:s doesn't have support for IPv6.
You do not need to set up anything else than a tunnel and a firewall to start using IPv6.  Most services are IPv6 ready.

Answer (score 1):

The following question covers much of the same ground, but is not *ubuntu-centric:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1634/ipv6-for-home-users

Answer (score 0):

Randomly generated private IPv6 address range:
http://www.simpledns.com/private-ipv6.aspx

Check your IPv4/6 connectivity:
http://test-ipv6.com/

Answer (score 0):

SixXS provide a very helpful FAQ to various aspects of IPv6: http://www.sixxs.net/faq/

The Linux Kernel itself has IPv6 support since Linux 2.6 - at least since 2004. Most applications shipped with Ubuntu support IPv6 at least since Ubuntu 10.04 (This is the first version, with which I played around with IPv6). Normally you don't have to configure anything to work with IPv6, I just does.